# Upload Image though PHP, save Image path to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Sure this is a easy one for you experts, I`m trying to upload a image to the site and save the path to the database. If possible, how can i change the image size before saving?

Here is my script that handles to update query when updating:

```
<?php   // Get Event ID
    $update=$_GET['update'];

    // Create Session
    $event_name=$_POST['event_name'];
    $event_description=$_POST['event_description'];
    $event_date=$_POST['event_date'];
    $event_time=$_POST['event_time'];
    $event_cost=$_POST['event_cost'];
    $event_image=$_POST['event_image'];

    // Connection to MySQL Database.
    include ('_includes/_dbconnection.php');
    include ('_includes/_dbopen.php');

    // Update Event using Event ID.

    $sql="UPDATE b_events SET ename = '$event_name', edescription = '$event_description', edate = '$event_date', etime = '$event_time', ecost = '$event_cost', eimage = '$event_image' WHERE id = '$update'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    if($result){
    header('Location: _events.php');
    }

    else {
    header('Location: _home.php');
    }

?>
```

I have the following code in the update.html for the image:

```
<input name="event_image" type="file" />
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/386581/1220835

Answer (score 0):

To change the image size must resize. A function to create a copy with specific dimensions.

```
<?php
// File and new size
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($thumb);
?>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

Answer (score 0):

Php has GD library for working with images: function imagecopyresampled resize an image. Verify that GD is enalbed in you php config
https://www.php.net/imagecopyresampled